# What is the max level for the Arm's Manufacturers?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

You have to give Miranium to Arm's Manufacturers or wear their equipment to level them up. What is the max level an Arms Manufacturer can get to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The max level for all Arms Manufacturers is 5. Note that half of them are unlocked via sidequests, and not the main story.